# R Package Dependency in Github via Remotes not working

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I'm developing an R package in Github ([ConceptionTools](https://github.com/IMI-ConcePTION/ConceptionTools)) that depends on another R package ([CreateFlowChart](https://github.com/IMI-ConcePTION/CreateFlowChart)), also in Github. I have followed [the instructions for defining remote dependencies](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/vignettes/dependencies.html). My DESCRIPTION file includes:

```
Imports: CreateFlowChart
Remotes: github::IMI-ConcePTION/CreateFlowChart
```

However, when I install my package, with the command:

```
devtools::install_github("IMI-ConcePTION/ConceptionTools")
```

This dependency is not installed. I simply get "skipping 1 packages not available: CreateFlowChart". It doesn't appear to be trying to use the Remote, since there is no error related to Github.

When I install the dependency directly, that works:

```
devtools::install_github("IMI-ConcePTION/CreateFlowChart")
```

Does anybody have any idea of what could be going on here? I'm racking my brain, as it seems to be a quite straightforward case of what the documentation shows. I'm using R 4.0.3 (on Windows 10) and devtools 2.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a typo in the name of the dependency package in its `DESCRIPTION` file.

This does not make the package fail when installing it directly, but it leads devtools not to find it as a dependency.